# Android Studio: Expand autocompleted object after intellisense insert

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio

Working with Flutter/Dart. Whenever I use intellisense to autocomplete something, it shows up like this:

```
Expanded(child: child)
```

I'd rather it show up like this:

```
Expanded(
  child: child
)
```

Is there a setting for this in Android Studio? If not, is there an add-on I can install that does this?